# Reading JSON object with jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to deserialize the following json object with jackson:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "endpoints": [
            {
                "name": "Tester",
                "id": "48aba1b3-3585-4327-a20f-627a1749611b",
                "componentId": "Darwin2",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "network": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "appWans": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "services": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "endpointGroups": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "geoRegion": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    },
                    "dataCenter": {
                        "href": "www.google.com"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "first": {
            "href": "www.google.com"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "www.google.com"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 2000,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 1
    }
}
```

My goal is to implement an `Embedded` object then within this object add another object called `Endpoints`. Ideally, I'd be able to access the id property off of the endpoints object. However, I keep getting deserialization errors. For the moment I am using this class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@lombok.Value
public class Endpoints {

  @JsonProperty("_embedded")
  private Map<String, Object> embedded = new HashMap<>();

}
```

This at least affords me the opportunity to do the following:

```
 Endpoints result = apiRequest.get();
    if (result != null) System.out.println(result.getEmbedded().get("endpoints"));
```

Which prints out the array of endpoints, but I can't use this. I must implement a java object. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this issue.

Comment: What? Lombok doesn't (de)serialize JSON - it just autogenerates some Java boilerplate code. It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what `apiRequest.get();` is and what it returns. Will this return a String? An already serialized Object? The library you use and the method signature would be great.

Comment: Also, the format looks like HAL-json. Are you using Spring HATEOAS or Spring Data REST?

Comment: Why don't you just create a class for each nested object ? Jackson will figure it out. This feels like it has nothing to do with Lombok.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer the return from apiRequest.get() is the json object. I'm using HATEOAS.  Apologies for lack of knowledge I am refactoring old code.

Comment: @EvanGertis what "json object"? A string, containing the JSON you showed, or an actual Java object? Makes a lot of difference, bc. you need to first deserialize a string. Furthermore, some context on the framework would be good, bc. I can give you a solution using plain Java and Jacskon, but if you have all the Spring dependencies, you can just use their code. Also, Spring normally takes care of deserialization if used correctly, so I am very puzzled at what you are doing here.

Answer (score -1):

So I have no idea what frameworks you use, or where this JSON data comes from, but you mentioned Spring HATEOS, so here is a solution using Jackson and Spring HATEOAS:

```
@Data
public class Endpoint extends RepresentationModel<Endpoint> {
    private String name;
    private String id; // Could be a UUID type instead??
    private String componentId;
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void foo() {
        String mysteryString = apiRequest.get();
        PagedModel<Endpoint> endpointsPage = objectMapper.readValue(mysteryString, new TypeReference<PagedModel<Endpoint>>);
        
        for (Endpoint e : endpointsPage) {
            System.out.println(e.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

[Spring HATEOAS docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) and a [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/). Also look at the Javadoc of the classes I've used.

If you want `Endpoint` to be a Lombok Value (i.e., all final), you need a constructor with appropriate ´@JsonCreator´ and ´@JsonProperty´ annotations, so Jackson knows how to build your Object (see 'guide' link).

And some more reading on [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Then again, if you are using Spring and you could just use [Spring RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) to fetch the Data from the remote API, you don't even need to manually use Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
PagedModel<Endpoint> endpointsPage = 
    restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, 
                          HttpMethod.GET, 
                          null, // RequestEntity (body of request)
                          new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedModel<Endpoint>>() {}).getBody();
```

The whole `TypeReference` and `ParameterizedTypeReference` business is only needed bc. we are dealing with generics.

Comment: Did you actually test your code?